# calculate total number after retrieving subtotal of each item within a query with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables `tbl_order` which is the parent of `tbl_order_product`: each product in `tbl_order_product` has its own `quantity`, `price`, and `discount` that is important to count as the total price, also each order has its own `discount` to, I want to make a query that gets the total price of each order which needs to calculate the total price of each product inside that order, then sum them up and calculate it with the discount of the order itself, I was able to achieve this with a query which I don't think is an efficient way like this:

```
select o.id, count(op.id) as productsCount,

--calculating the total price
sum(op.price * op.quantity - op.price * op.quantity * op.discount / 100) -
sum(op.price * op.quantity - op.price * op.quantity * op.discount / 100) * o.discount / 100 as total

from tbl_order as o
inner join tbl_payment_type as pt on o.payment_type_id = pt.id
inner join tbl_customer as c on o.customer_id = c.id
inner join tbl_order_product as op on o.id = op.order_id
inner join tbl_user as u on o.created_by = u.id
group by o.id, o.discount
```

I believe there could be a better to achieve the same thing which i don't know how

`tbl_order`:
[image: tbl_order]

`tbl_order_product`:
[image: tbl_order_product]

result of my query:
[image: the result of my query]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why do you feel that the query isn't efficient? What isn't efficient about it?

Comment: @Larnu I am not that much skilled with SQL databases and I thought there could be a better way to do what I want

Comment: @Larnu or do you think that would be a great idea if I store the total price of an order with it self?, I am thinking that is wrong especially if they come back and change some items in the order

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your current approach. I deal with an ERP every day. Most ERPs store an order header and order lines separately. Individual product pricing is usually stored with the lines along with line-level discounts. The order header does not usually contain a total. The order header may contain information such salesreps, shipping data, etc. In my ERP, even tax rates are stored on the line level because each line in a sales order can be shipped from different locations and so be governed by different tax jurisdictions.

Comment: The only issue I have with your query is the ambiguous math. I would add more parentheses to properly group your terms. For example, is this more correct? `sum( ((op.price * op.quantity) - (op.price * op.quantity * op.discount)) / 100)`. What are your discount values? A percentage, a flat dollar value (or whatever local currency denomination you use), a quantity break, etc.? Depending on your industry, you could calculate the total without discount and the discount value separately, then you list both on your Order Acknowledgement or Invoices so the customer sees the benefit of buying from you

Comment: It looks good. For style points you could do:
sum(op.price * op.quantity - op.price * op.quantity * op.discount / 100) * ( 1 - o.discount / 100)

Comment: @siggemannen actually I ended up using the same thing, but since I had that calculation in many places I made it as a custom function

Comment: @TimJarosz thank you for clarifying, i have added those other things but not here since I wanted to show my problem clear